# Doctrine event subscribers - performance and convention

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener

I've got a basic question regarding the *right* way to do things in Symfony2, with specific emphasis on Doctrine event subscribers. I know how to implement them, but something has been bugging me. Currently, I have the following class.

```
namespace MyProject\MainBundle\EventSubscriber;


use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use MyBundle\MainBundle\Entity\LandingPageAggregator;

class LandingPageAggregatorSubscriber implements EventSubscriber {
    /**
     * Returns an array of events this subscriber wants to listen to.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            'prePersist',
            'preUpdate',
        );
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        if (!$entity instanceof LandingPageAggregator)
            return;
        // Adittional stuff here...
    }
}
```

I got this from [this Symfony article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html), and it's working fine, my question is just the following:

1. Is there a better way to do this? Is this actually the accepted standard way of setting stuff like "Posted By" or "Created Date" fields?
2. Is this not performance intensive? Forgive me if I'm wrong, but registering 100 of these, doesn't that mean that for every single persist to the database, Symfony has to run thorugh all 100 subscribers and call the `prePersist` method on each of them? This seems like a giant waste of resources, thus the purpose of this question.
3. If I'm correct with number 2. above here, is there any better/less intensive method of doing the same thing? I just read on [doctrine's documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) that they've introduced a new annotation as of 2.4, but I'm not using that version yet. Will that solve this issue in any case?

As a side question, what is the difference between the listener and subscriber as stated in the Symfony documentation linked above?

Thanks for any advice here!

Comment: Side answer: Listeners have no getSubscribedEvents() method. In this case it's the responsibility of the service definiton to define the events to listen to, see: 

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: You're doing everything right, there is no other options to correctly implement such things except using event subscribers.

Comment: @Hast So am I correct in saying that it incurs a large performance penalty if you have say 100 listeners? Or is this mitigated by the cache? Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Nope on the performance.  The entity manager maintains a list of all objects that have subscribed to the prePersist event.  So it's just a loop calling a method.  You have already created and persisted these 100 objects so one more call is not going to add much to that.  Do be careful with preUpdate.  It seldom works the way people expect.

Comment: In additional to what @Cerad `preUpdated()` works really strange and often not working at all.

Comment: @Cerad, why is that? Can one of you please post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I know this is an old post, and links are not recommended, but this post explains the solution : http://culttt.com/2014/08/04/understanding-doctrine-2-lifecycle-events/